# Sync the position / page of sideloaded EPUB books between Android device and Nook Touch?

Tags: sync, epub

Is it possible to sync the current position / page of an EPUB book between two devices?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PageTurner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nightwhistler.pageturner.ads) on Google Play. It's supposed to do what you want, although there are some mixed reviews. It's worth a try though.

> PageTurner is an open-source e-book reader that allows you to sync
>   your reading progress across devices, without needing a DropBox or
>   Google Drive account... just enter your e-mail address and it works!

Comment: I tried it but it's ugly as sin

Comment: @Ze'ev There are probably similar apps around.

Comment: Well that's what I'm asking!